# Absolute convergence of series with cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Consider the series:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits _{n=1}^{+\infty}\cos\left(nx\right)\cos\left(ny\right),\quad x,y \in \left(0,\pi\right)
\end{equation}
What is the easiest way to prove that the series converges absolutely for $x\neq y$?

Comment: It is divergent for $x=0,y=2\pi$. The general term does not event tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not converge absolutely, since for $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $y=\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ and $n=4k$ we get:

$|cos(k\pi)||cos3k\pi|=1.1=1$ . Summing over all $n=4k, k=1,2,3,...$

we get that the series diverges!